# Finding best representative point in a group of latitudes and longitudes

Tags: python

I have a cluster of 10 Latitudes and Longitudes. I want to find the optimal location to do set up a lemonade stand.

So in other words, I need to find the best representative point of the group of latitudes and longitudes.

I’m aware of how to find the centroid (center), but I don’t necessarily want the centroid.

I just want to find what point (latitude, longitude) is best representative of the cluster.

Im a beginning python learner, so I’m having a little trouble finding some approaches. I’d really appreciate it if someone can link sources or name some methods as to how I can do this.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do - is this a Python problem or a geospatial one? There's other StackExchange sites which specialise in that.

Comment: isnt that the definition of the centroid? do you have an example where the centroid is not   correct?  do you want to eliminate outliers first and then find the centroid maybe? what you are trying to do is not very well explained... please define "best representative point" if it is not the centroid

Comment: Find the centroid of the group of points (essentially the mean), then find the point closest to the centroid (the median) by calculating distance to the centroid for each point, then select the point with smallest distance to the centroid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Centroid is basically average of your latitudes and longitudes
so the easiest way to find one is by

```py
latsum = sum(latitudes)
lonsum = sum(longitudes)
centroid = (latsum/len(latitudes) , lonsum/len(longitudes))
```

The sum function does what it says and the len function gives you the length of list which in your case is 10.
Since you mentioned that the best representative is what you need, you might need to clear out any outliers in your data.

https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-use-statistics-to-identify-outliers-in-data/

This is a good resource for you to start understanding making data science operations in python.